# Matsubara sum in mean field theory of superfluid

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, superfluidity

Ths system is given in [Doppler shift in current-carrying superfluid](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/633812/doppler-shift-in-current-carrying-superfluid). Here to make mean-field theory, we set $\vec{Q}=0$ and $\Delta(x)=\Delta_{0}$.

After some manipulations, we obtain the thermaldynamical potential due to fermion excitaion
$$\Omega_{F}=\frac{\Delta^{2}_{0}}{\beta}-\sum\limits_{i\omega_{n},\vec{k}}\text{Tr}\ln(-G_{0}^{-1}(i\omega_n,\vec{k}))$$.

The followings steps are my calculations:

1. For fixed $\vec{k}$ and $\omega_n$, the eigenvalues of $-G_{0}^{-1}(i\omega_n,\vec{k}))$ are $-i\omega_{n}+\sqrt{(\frac{\vec{k}^{2}}{2m}-\mu)^{2}+\Delta^{2}_{0}}$ and  $-i\omega_{n}-\sqrt{(\frac{\vec{k}^{2}}{2m}-\mu)^{2}+\Delta^{2}_{0}}$
2. Therefore $\text{Tr}\ln(-G(i\omega_{n},\vec{k}))=\ln(-i\omega_{n}+\sqrt{(\frac{\vec{k}^{2}}{2m}-\mu)^{2}+\Delta^{2}_{0}})+\ln{(-i\omega_{n}-\sqrt{(\frac{\vec{k}^{2}}{2m}-\mu)^{2}+\Delta^{2}_{0}})}
   $
3. Since matsubara sum for fermion matsubara frequency:
   $$\sum\limits_{\omega_{n}}\ln{(-i\omega_{n}+\xi)}=\ln{(1+e^{-\beta\xi})}$$
   note $\sqrt{(\frac{\vec{k}^{2}}{2m}-\mu)^{2}+\Delta^{2}_{0}})$ as $E_{\vec{k}}$, we would directly have
   $$\Omega_{F}=\frac{\Delta^{2}_{0}}{\beta}-\sum_{\vec{k}}E_{\vec{k}}-\sum_{\vec{k}}\frac{2}{\beta}\ln{[1+e^{-\beta E_{\vec{k}}}]}\tag{1}$$

However, in all textbooks and paper, $\Omega_{F}$ is $\Omega^{True}_{F}$
$$\Omega^{True}_{F}=\frac{\Delta^{2}_{0}}{\beta}+\sum_{\vec{k}}(\frac{\vec{k}^{2}}{2m}-\mu)-\sum_{\vec{k}}E_{\vec{k}}-\sum_{\vec{k}}\frac{2}{\beta}\ln{[1+e^{-\beta E_{\vec{k}}}]}\tag{2}$$

Clearly, (1) and (2) differ by $\sum_{\vec{k}}(\frac{\vec{k}^{2}}{2m}-\mu)$, yet I cannot find what goes wrong. Could anyong help?